# EC2 cannot access to EFS

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, amazon-efs

Our website has mounted on 4 EC2 and 1 EFS. Sometimes EC2 servers cannot access to EFS. When I run commands like cd and ls, they are not responding when access is not available.

- When I restart the server, the problem goes away.
- 1 or more servers may experience the same problem.
- Some servers can still access EFS.

Can you help me with this?